# Python KustoManagementClient using my own credentials

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-authentication

I'm trying to use [azure-mgmt-kusto](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-kusto/) Pkg for some Kusto Cluster operations, using KustoManagementClient. This client requires TokenCredential on constructor. 
 For my own scenario, I would like to use my own AAD credentials, preferably using interactive login or IWA (Integrated Windows Authentication).
 The closest I was able to achieve this is using the following code:

```
creds = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_interactive_browser_credential=False).get_token('')
kusto_client = azure.mgmt.kusto.KustoManagementClient(credential=creds, subscription_id='<>')
```

but this raises an error in the second line:

> Expected type 'TokenCredential', got 'AccessToken' instead

which I couldn't find any way around!
Any suggestions on how to resolve this? or other methods to use?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after simply trying despite the Pycharm warning, this worked:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.kusto import KustoManagementClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
kusto_management_client = KustoManagementClient(credential, subId)
```